# How slowly can $f$ grow to have $\lim_{a\to +\infty}\frac{1}{a}\int_0^a \sin(f(x)+t)dx=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Consider a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^+,\mathbb R)$ such that $f'(x)>0$, $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

How slowly can $f$ grow to $+\infty$ in order to have
$$
\lim_{a\to +\infty}\frac{\int_0^a \sin(f(x)+t)dx}a=0
$$
for any $t \in [0,2 \pi)$?

I tested that $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ satisfies the contition apparently for any $\alpha$ while $f(x)=\ln(x)$ produces a non convergent limit. Is it correct to think that any function slower than $\ln(x)$ will still produce a non convergent limit? Is $\ln(x)$ the fastest function that doesn't converge?

(It seems L'Hôpital's rule - deriving wrt $a$ - doesn't help here).

Comment: The integral is with respect to $\;t\;$ or to $\;x\;$? Perhaps it had to be $\;\sin(f(x)+x)\;$ ?

Comment: If $f'\to\infty$ and $f'$ is eventually monotone, $f$ satisfies your condition (because $\int_0^{\infty} \sin f$ converges under said conditions)

Comment: @Joanpemo corrected

Comment: @JulienGodawatta great but what happens with a slow growing $f$?

Comment: @JulienGodawatta: I would be interested in knowing how to prove that. Could you give me a hint? :)

Comment: @PhoemueX Sure, the conditions imply a couple useful things: $f$ is invertible on $[R,\infty)$ for some $R$ (enabling the substitution $t=f(x)$), and for some $N$, $f(\xi_0)=2N\pi$ (which then gives you $\xi_1<\xi_2<\cdots$ where $f(\xi_k)=(2N+k)\pi$). You will only need $f'\to\infty$ at the very end.